# PHPSpreadsheet - How to read row value from xlsx by table heading name?

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Currently, I'm changing from `maatwebsite/excel` to use `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`. Refer to this [Table heading as attributes.](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) so I think maybe new library could not support access row value by table heading name.

Have any the same way to read data when using PHPSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table headings in `PHPSpreadsheet` are the column addresses (A, B, C, D, etc), not the values of any arbitrary row or rows (because there will be people that use multiple row headings in their sheet data), so the answer is no; though it's easy enough for you to convert an array read from a row to an associative array based on values from a single "heading" row using `array_combine()`